# Different Audio on front and rear channels

Tags: audio

**Motherboard :** Gigabyte G31MS2L

**Drivers Realtek:** 6.0.1.6235

I want to have Skype on the blue jack and Windows Media Player on green. Is that possible?

Here's my current setup:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this **requires both hardware and software support**. I'm pretty sure the distinction between your speaker and headphone ports is how much power is pushed out on them. In other words, I seriously seriously doubt you can drive them as separate audio devices.

To practically accomplish this, you'll likely need another sound card. Provided you actually get one going, you'll still need OS-level support. I have no idea if *Windows 7* can let you select what audio device is used for output for individual apps. I'm going to assume not.

If I were really really keen to get this effect, I'd probably try to write my own video player (hopefully you can write an interface that extends Windows Media Player - or, just extend VLC or mplayer). Through that, I'd seek to output that audio to a secondary sound card. Still not convinced of how easy that'll be.

I suggest you consider just using a second machine, if you really need this functionality. Use Synergy to share a single Keyboard and Mouse between them, if that helps you.

Edit: Based on other answers provided, it sounds like some sound cards do in fact provide the required hardware functionality to accomplish this. Make sure you've got any hardware specific utilities installed and poke around them to see if you can some how change a setting to run your front and back ports as separate audio devices. Still, some level of OS/application support would be required to use that - though judging by some comments here, *Windows 7* probably has some means of managing that.

Comment: Actually, it requires driver and software support. And the software already supports it.

Comment: Which software? The OS, the application? I don't think explicit driver support is strictly required. Unless you had a sound card that is built to do this - which I'd argue would then be multiple sound cards in one device.. or at least, managed by a single driver.

Comment: Technically, WMP already allows you to choose which device to output the sound. If you have independent front and back speakers, just select the ones you want under WMP Options/Devices/Sound. Most software these days allow you to choose which device to output sound. Others on the list: VLC and MPC.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is some sort of advanced audio driver that can create two virtual stereo sound cards whose channels are mapped to channels on the physical sound card. Unfortunately I don't know of any that can do that.

Once you get that going, just go into the preferences of the applications in question and have them each use the appropriate virtual audio device.

Comment: This could only work if the audio hardware was built with distinct D to A converters for each output port. I don't think sound cards are made that way as that'd be a waste of (cheap) hardware. Instead, my money is on the bet that they use a single D to A pair for all output and then amplify/load balance the two ports separately. But, I *could* be wrong. I don't think so though. I believe in practical terms, Nikhil will require a separate sound card - and even then, still need OS or Application level support.

Comment: There's no need for separate DACs as long as each virtual audio device only supported a single, same frequency. The driver could recombine the streams, filling in the unused channels with silence.

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with providing two distinct audio outputs?

Comment: The asker doesn't *need* two distinct outputs, he just needs two audio devices that *seem* independent but instead go to different channels of the same output device.

Comment: Well, if they wanted mono sound, and did some minor cable modding, they could use a single stereo port to this end. Anyway... Moving on..

Comment: Sure, I don't see why not. But the asker presumably has more than two channels, as would be required for "front and rear channels".

Answer (score 0):

I have a Gigabyte motherboard with Realtek audio stuff as well. In my case I have a program called Realtek HD Audio Manager, maybe you have something similar? Came with the audio drivers.

Anyways, in that program, in the upper right corner there's a link which says `Device advanced settings`. Click on that and I get a dialog where I can choose "Make front and rear output devices playback two different audio streams simultaneously".

**Edit:** Didn't notice your blue and green requirement thing. What I was talking about was to make the front and back jacks work as separate devices... that way you can connect your speakers to the back, and your skype headset to the front for example :)

Comment: Wow, nice, sounds like there really are separate sound cards implemented within Realtek's audio gear you've got. Good for them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. I'm surprised that you get sound out of the blue, cause blue is usually a line **IN**. If both of them are line outs, again, it is unlikely they are seen as two outputs, but rather one audio output split into two ports.

Comment: Realtek HD Audio Manager allows to change the function of any jack! I can even use the pink one for sound output.

Comment: Interesting! Then moving applications from one device to the other is quite possible then.  Well, the application has to support it because if it is using the low level api calls to do sound, then it will crash if the OS moves it. But I know WMP does it user Option/Devices/Speakers.  Just make sure to name your ports under Control Panel to make it easier.